# Packaging a Git Gem for Deployment to Ruby Lambda Runtime

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, rubygems

I am building a Ruby 2.7 Lambda application.

My application depends on a gem that exists in github.

```
gem 'my-gem', git: 'https://github.com/my-org/my-gem', branch: 'main'
```

I want to write a script that can build a deployment zip file containing this dependency.

When I run `bundle install`, my gem is installed to vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/gems/my-gem-GITHASH.

For Lambda packaging, I believe that I need construct the following

- vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/my-gem-1.0.0/* (ruby code)
- vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/specifications/my-gem-1.0.0.gemspec

The following scripted actions can assemble this structure, but I wish I had a simpler approach.

```
    cd vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/gems/my-gem-* 
    # build the git gem (*.gem)
    gem build 
    # copy the gem and the gemspec to the vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0 directories
    cp *.gem ../../../gems 
    cp *.gemspec ../../../specifications/my-gem-1.0.0.gemspec 
    # upack the .gem file in the proper directory
    cd ../../../gems 
    gem unpack *.gem 
    # return to the working directory
    cd ../../../../.. 
    # Zip the dependencies 
    zip -r deploy.zip \
           vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems \
           vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/specifications \
           vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions \
           lib
```

I would be curious to find a simpler approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to add the `bundler/gems` path to the `$LOAD_PATH`, like so:

```rb
load_paths = Dir['./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/gems/**/lib']
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(*load_paths)
```

(at the very top of `lambda_function.rb`)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me in Sinatra. If you don't want to hardcode the ruby version use: './vendor/bundle/ruby/**/bundler/gems/**/lib'

Answer (score 0):

Running `bundle install --deployment` should do what you want ([documentation page](https://bundler.io/guides/deploying.html#manual-deployment)).

Update: It seems that [the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-package.html#ruby-package-dependencies) use `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`.

Comment: That won't work for gems bundled from git/github paths.

Comment: @PawełGościcki I just tried it, and it does in fact work. Would you care to share what gem is causing issues for you? Got any more information?

Comment: `gem 'mandrill-api', require: 'mandrill', github: 'workstory/mandrill-api-ruby'`